# What is the probability that all extracted balls are pink?

Tags: probability

Three balls are extracted at random - with **replacement** - from a box with two
pink, three blue and four green balls. What is the probability that all extracted balls are pink? But **without replacement** that all extracted balls are green?

Comment: Chance of getting one pink is $2/9$. And you are extracting 3 balls. Can you do it from here?

Comment: Spig gafigg clolhoople.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, it's obviously $(\frac{2}{9})^3$

For the second part, it's obviously $(\frac{4}{9})(\frac{3}{8})(\frac{2}{7})$ since you don't return the balls (and so the counts of the green and total balls decreases each time you pull a ball).

Comment: what is formula which you applied?

Comment: Well, just common sense, and general rules applicable to these types of problems. Let me see if I can phrase it more formally.

Comment: How you obtain $(\frac{3}{9})(\frac{2}{8})(\frac{1}{7})$ ? what mean **without replacement** ? is a special formula to apply?

Comment: See e.g. http://www.chemical-ecology.net/java/prob1-s.htm

Comment: The probability for the 1st green ball is $3/9$. Then, well, because once you picked a green ball, you don't put it back. So you're left with 2 green balls and 8 balls in total. This makes the probability for the 2nd green ball $2/8$. And analogically to this, you proceed for the 3rd green ball. Finally you multiply the 3 probabilities.

Comment: but if we pick a green ball we remain with 3 green balls and 8 balls, not 9.. are you sure is **9** and not **8**?

Comment: and one more thing, the probability of first extraction isn't **3/9** is **4/9**

Comment: Since four of the nine balls are green, I obtain $\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{2}{7}$ for the second case.

Comment: Yes, $(\frac{4}{9})(\frac{3}{8})(\frac{2}{7})$ is the correct answer. I misread the problem statement, I thought we have 3 green balls in total. But ... you got the idea.